# ObservableCollection's CollectionChanged not firing

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection`, based on `List`.

```
private List<int> markers = new List<int>();
private ObservableCollection<int> markersObservable;

markersObservable = new ObservableCollection<int>(markers);
markersObservable.CollectionChanged += MarkersObservable_CollectionChanged;
```

When adding element into the list:

```
markers.Add(hScrollBarPoints.Value);
```

I expect collection changed event would fire, however, event never fired:

```
private void MarkersObservable_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Changed!");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `new ObservableCollection<int>(markers)` only copies all elements from `markers`, it doesn't form any kind of relation with the original collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add items to the `List`, the `ObservableCollection` is not changed and thus does not fire the `CollectionChanged` event.

To get the event fired, you have to add the item to the `ObservableCollection`:

```
markersObservable.Add(hScrollBarPoints.Value);
```

Comment: I specifically keep List<T> because I can sort it.

Comment: @Pablo that's a different problem all together, maybe try a CollectionView instead.